# How to delete Last Update date in wordpress' page?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm newbie in wordpress. I got website: http://xn--lnepengerprivat-hlb.com/ and on homepage (it's page, not a post!) I've got Last Update date. How to delete it? Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Add this css in your style.css or find in your theme file and remove the php code.

```
 .page-last-modified {
    display: none;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could hide the page post date by using CSS, either in a `styles.css` file or in the custom CSS editor of WP Customizer.

```
.page-last-modified {
    display: none;
}
```

Another solution would be to delete the whole block in the page template file of your child theme.